# I want to rotate a square matrix by 90 degrees anticlockwise, but the output is not what i need

Tags: c, matrix, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a square matrix, the reading working well, the displaying of initial matrix is working good, but when I call the rotate function, the output is very strange. I will attache the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// reading and allocation function 
int *citire_matrice (int *dim) {
   int i,j;
   int *m;

   if (* dim==0) {
        printf ("Introduceti numarul de linii si coloane al matricei (este o matrice patratica)=");
        scanf ("%d", dim);
   }
   m=(int*)malloc ( (*dim)*(*dim)*sizeof(int));

   if (!m) {
       printf ("Memoria nu a putut fi alocata.Iesire.");
       exit (1);
   }

   printf ("\n Citire valori matrice:\n");
   for (i=0;i<*dim;i++)
       for (j=0; j<*dim; j++) {
           printf("m[%d][%d]=",i+1,j+1);
           scanf("%d",m+*dim*i+j);
       }
   return m;
 }

//display function
void afisare_matrice (int *m,int dim) {
 int i,j;
 for (i=0;i<dim;i++) {
     for (j=0;j<dim;j++)
         printf ("%8d",*(m+dim*i+j));
         printf ("\n");
 }
}
 //rotate function

int* rotire_matrice (int*m,int dim) {
   int i,j,temp;
   int*p;

   p= (int*)malloc (dim*dim*sizeof (int));
   if (!p) { 
       printf ("nu s-a putut aloca memoria. Iesire");
       exit (1);
   } 

   for (i=0;i<dim;i++) {
       temp=0;
         for (j=0;j<dim;j++) {
           *(m+dim*(temp++)+i)=*(m+dim*(--dim)+i);
           *(p+dim*i+j) = *(m+dim*(temp++)+i);
       }
   }   

  return p;
}

//free memory
void eliberare_matrice (int *m) {
   if (m!= NULL)
   free(m);
}
int main () {

int *m,*p;
int dim=0,i,j;
m=citire_matrice(&dim);
printf ("\nmatricea initiala\n");
afisare_matrice(m,dim);
p = rotire_matrice(m,dim);
printf ("\nmatricea rotita\n");
afisare_matrice(p,dim);
eliberare_matrice (m);
eliberare_matrice (p);
system ("PAUSE");
return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
Introduceti numarul de linii si coloane al matricei (este o matrice patratica)=3

 Citire valori matrice:
m[1][1]=1
m[1][2]=2
m[1][3]=3
m[2][1]=4
m[2][2]=5
m[2][3]=6
m[3][1]=7
m[3][2]=8
m[3][3]=9

matricea initiala
   1       2       3
   4       5       6
   7       8       9

matricea rotita
   3       4 9961808
   0       0       0
   0       0       0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Please organize your code

Comment: And please indent/format your code correctly.

Comment: done with this, i think is more readable now

Comment: `*(m+dim*(temp++)+i)=*(m+dim*(--dim)+i);
           *(p+dim*i+j) = *(m+dim*(temp++)+i);` are wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I'll take your word for it..

Comment: Why is wrong? i don't get it

Comment: first, Please be aware that You are changing `dim`. Do not change in at least two(nest) loops.
And this includes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Besides, it probably does not expect change of `temp`, either.

Comment: i can't figure it out how to fix this

Comment: Please reconsider the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
int *rotire_matrice(int*m, int dim)
{
  int *p = (int*)malloc(dim*dim * sizeof(int));
  if (!p)
  {
    printf("nu s-a putut aloca memoria. Iesire");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (int x = 0; x<dim; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y<dim; y++) {
      int nx = y;
      int ny = dim - 1 - x;
      *(p + nx*dim + ny) = *(m + x*dim + y);
    }
  }
  return p;
}
```

Or more readable:

Define this macro:

```
 #define MAT(m,dim,x,y) (*((m) + (x)*(dim) + (y)))
```

and replace

```
  *(p + nx*dim + ny) = *(m + x*dim + y);
```

by

```
  MAT(p, dim, nx, ny) = MAT(m, dim, x, y);
```

Comment: Is working, but is clockwise, not anti-cloclwise. I'll try to do myself,if I'll achieve, I will let you know. Thank you

Comment: Anticlockwise is pretty similar, you should be able to figure it out by yourself. A piece of paper and a pencil are very helpful here.